# How to remove Line terminator from a file and save without it in python language?

Tags: debugging

When I am reading a CSV file, it is producing NAN rows in between the actual data (i.e. rows). When I read the file with line-terminator as "\n", the data-frame structure looks fine, the way I want. Could anyone explain what causes line-terminator to play a part while saving/reading the file? How to remove line-terminator permanently?

**Before line-terminator is added**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCh8x.jpg)

**After line-terminator is added**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrdhN.jpg)

Thanks